# Transpile async/await to Generator functions with tsc with target >= ES2017

Tags: typescript, tsc, zone.js

I hardly try to transpile async/await patterns to generator functions for targets >= ES2017 with tsc. This seems to be possible with babel (@babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-function or @babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator), but I try to stick with tsc only.

I would like to use zone.js for something, until we found a better solution. Becasue zone.js does not support native async/await, I look for workarounds.

Do you know, if tsc supports this now or soon? Thank you for any hint!

Best regards,
Dominic

Google research and I tried if any of https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/tree/main/src/lib could match my issue.